# How to access a variable defined in an outer function from inner function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dashboard where a dataframe is defined and displayed based upon the parameters chosen by the user. I would like to add a button that allows the user to download the dataframe, that it is previously defined, when it is clicked.
The following is the function that I defined to define and to display the dataframe:

```
def filtra_dati(selezione, canale, metrica):
    output.clear_output()
        
    if canale == "ALL":
        df = canali_weekly.loc[(slice(None), slice(selezione[0],selezione[1])), list(metrica)]  
    else:
        df = canali_weekly.loc[(canale, slice(selezione[0],selezione[1])), list(metrica)]
    
    with output:
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
        display(df)
```

I tried to nest a new function (`on_button_clicked()`) to add the download button:

```
def filtra_dati(selezione, canale, metrica):
    output.clear_output()
        
    if canale == "ALL":
        df = canali_weekly.loc[(slice(None), slice(selezione[0],selezione[1])), list(metrica)]  
    else:
        df = canali_weekly.loc[(canale, slice(selezione[0],selezione[1])), list(metrica)]
    
    with output:
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
        display(df)
        
    def on_button_clicked(b):
        with output:
            print("Button clicked.")
            df.to_excel("~/Downloads/df.xlsx")
```

But it doesn't work and I get the error that the dataframe is not defined, which makes me think that I'am not able to access the variable defined above with this solution.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0246293b959d> in on_button_clicked(b)
     42     with output:
     43         print("Button clicked.")
---> 44         df.to_excel("~/Downloads/df.xlsx")
     45 
     46 

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

I [read something](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure#:%7E:text=A%20function%20defined%20inside%20another,in%20order%20to%20modify%20them.) about nesting function but I'm not sure that is what I am looking for.

**EDIT**
This is the full code:

```
kpi = [k for k in canali_weekly.columns]
dropdown_canali = widgets.Dropdown(options = crea_opzioni_con_ALL(canali_weekly.index.get_level_values(level=0)), description='Canali:')
select_metriche = widgets.SelectMultiple(options=kpi, value= kpi, rows=5, description='Metriche:')

download_dataframe = widgets.Button(description='Scarica i dati', icon='check')

def filtra_dati(selezione, canale, metrica):
    output.clear_output()
        
    if canale == "ALL":
        df = canali_weekly.loc[(slice(None), slice(selezione[0],selezione[1])), list(metrica)]  
    else:
        df = canali_weekly.loc[(canale, slice(selezione[0],selezione[1])), list(metrica)]
    
    with output:
        pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
        pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
        display(df)
        
    def on_button_clicked(b):
        with output:
            print("Button clicked.")
            df.to_excel("~/Downloads/df.xlsx")


        
        
def week_eventhandler(change):
    filtra_dati(change.new, dropdown_canali.value, select_metriche.value)       

def canali_eventhandler(change):
    filtra_dati(intRange_week.value, change.new, select_metriche.value)     
    
def metriche_eventhandler(change):
    filtra_dati(intRange_week.value, dropdown_canali.value, change.new) 
    
intRange_week.observe(week_eventhandler, names='value')
dropdown_canali.observe(canali_eventhandler, names='value')
select_metriche.observe(metriche_eventhandler, names='value')

download_dataframe.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

Comment: How are you actually using `on_button_clicked`?  This should have worked, but your actual code obviously differs from what you posted (as the posted code never uses that function).

Comment: What I posted is the actual code (just the part of interest). I don't understand why you say that this code doesn't use the function? I add the entire code for safe.

Comment: A nested function is not accessible - indeed, it doesn't even *exist* - outside of the containing function, UNLESS you return it or store it somewhere external to the function.  You didn't do any such thing, so the `on_button_clicked` being referenced in the last line of your code cannot possibly be the nested function.  Either you've got a separate definition of `on_button_clicked` somewhere (which wouldn't have any access to the `df` local variable), or it isn't actually nested inside `filtra_dati()`.

Comment: Would you please link me a page where this is fully explained?